# Is it possible to create a "silent" Android app?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm creating a extremely simple app for Android 2.2: the only thing that does is to open an URL using the default browser.
When the app icon is clicked for a short time there is a black screen with the app name at the top before opening the browser.
Is this unavoidable when launching an app or is there any trick to make the app "silent", i.e., to jump instantly to the browser?

Here's what I've tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); Don't even show layout        
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Just to be on the safe side I also put android:visibility="gone" in activity_main.xml.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using theme Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar

Translucent makes you transparent by default, no title bar kills the title bar.